# Trying to Use multi EF model in Controller using LINQ MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I am trying to use multi EF model in Controller using LINQ my code is,

```
public JsonResult Index(int prefix)
{
    List<Survey_Response> ResponseList = new List<Survey_Response>();
    SurveyAppEntities ObjectSur = new SurveyAppEntities();           
    ObjectSur.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    ResponseList = (from r in ObjectSur.Survey_Response
                   join q in ObjectSur.Questions on r.SurveyID equals q.ID
                   where r.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
                   select new { r.QuestionID, q.Text, r.Response, r.FilledBy }).ToList();
    return Json(ResponseList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have two entities "Suervey_Response" and "Questions" i need data from both of them

```
Entity "Survey_Response" is like,

    public partial class Survey_Response
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SurveyID { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string Response { get; set; }
        public int FilledBy { get; set; }

        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
        public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Linq query is giving conversion type error Anonymous  on this line,

```
select new { r.QuestionID, q.Text, r.Response, r.FilledBy }).ToList();
```

If i put "r" in place of these selected values it works fine.

Hopes for your suggestion

Comment: What kind of message you've got with anonymous list? Sounds that since using `select r` working fine, there should related with EF references.

Comment: This is the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Survey.Survey_Response>'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem caused by assigning an list of anonymous type which contains result from multiple table joins into `List<Survey_Response>` collection, which cannot be implicitly converted. You should create another class to obtain query results like this:

**Model (Placeholder)**

```
public class SurveyVM
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public int FilledBy { get; set; }
}
```

And use that class inside LINQ query as in example below:

**Controller Action**

```
public JsonResult Index(int prefix)
{
    List<SurveyVM> ResponseList = new List<SurveyVM>();
    SurveyAppEntities ObjectSur = new SurveyAppEntities();           
    ObjectSur.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    ResponseList = (from r in ObjectSur.Survey_Response
                   join q in ObjectSur.Questions on r.SurveyID equals q.ID
                   where r.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
                   select new SurveyVM 
                   { 
                       QuestionID = r.QuestionID, 
                       Text = q.Text, 
                       Response = r.Response, 
                       FilledBy = r.FilledBy 
                   }).ToList();
    return Json(ResponseList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note that you can neither use `Survey_Response` nor `Question` as table name mentioned inside `select new` statement, you need third class definition which contains all properties defined in both tables.